# Can I include 'import web browser' in a function?

Tags: python, visual-studio, import, python-webbrowser

Is it possible to do this?

```
def viewbrowser():
      import webbrowser.open(xxx)
```

thank you in advance. I am still learning so please bear with me! :) Thank you for your understanding

Comment: You can try it out yourself

Comment: If you try, you will notice that the line is not valid Python syntax (at any position the code).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you should split it to 2 lines.

And it's not used as usual, why do you want to use import in function?

```
def viewbrowser(xxx_should_be_here):
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open(xxx_should_be_here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but do this -

```
def viewbrowser():
      import webbrowser
      webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/')
```